# docker doesn't install package enviirons

Tags: python, django, docker

I am trying to install a package "environs" in docker using the command docker-compose exec web pipenv install 'environs [django] == 8.0.0', however nothing happens in the terminal and the package is not installed in the container. What is the reason?
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - "DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=django-insecure-c@p4-@$$@#0deu2p5&-59#-1kv&@(ayfu*b+a+wt(i9j5p7&=p3"

  db:
    image: postgres:11
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust"
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8
# Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
# Set work directory
WORKDIR /code
# Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system
# Copy project
COPY . /code/
```

Comment: Anything you install in a running container will get lost as soon as the container exits.  I'd run that command in your host development environment to update the `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock` files, then re-run `docker-compose up --build` to rebuild the image with the new packages.

Comment: Do you suggest running the command in a virtual environment?

Comment: Outside Docker, in a virtual environment, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the working directory.

`docker-compose exec --workdir /code web pipenv install 'environs [django] == 8.0.0'`

Comment: is this the path where my project is located?

Comment: It is what your Dockerfile says

Comment: i used this command but also nothing happened.

Comment: Not any mesasge or output?

Comment: Strange. Where are you running this command, in a local shell?

Comment: i can't create app too https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YpGcF50ofZ8&ab_channel=zeratul314